# Administrar Usuarios

Tags: laravel

tengo una duda, estoy realizando un módulo de administración de usuarios en Laravel, he habilitado las rutas con:

> php artisan make:auth

Sin embargo no quiero utilizar el controlador que trae por defecto, si no uno aparte. He realizado la inserción de datos exitosamente, pero me percate que no me deja iniciar sesión si creo el usuario con otro controlador y si lo creo con el controlador que trae por default si.

Cuál es el problema, alguien me explique cuál es el problema y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Has modificado tus rutas?

Answer (score 1):

Al nuevo modelo que vas a utilizar para administrar los usuarios debes incorporarle lo siguiente

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
```

y en la declaración del modelo pondrías lo siguiente:

```
class NUEVO_MODELO extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, ShinobiTrait;
```

haciendo un extends a `Authenticatable` estas diciendo que este nuevo modelo es el que va a solicitar los metodos de seguridad de tu sistema.

Si deseas adicionar algo para que la administración de permisos te sea mas fácil de usar te recomiendo `shinobi`, es muy facil su instalación y su uso:

[SHINOBI](https://github.com/caffeinated/shinobi)

Answer (score 1):

Se puede deber a varias cosas:

1.- Estas utilizando las rutas que vienen por defecto y estas a puntan a otro métodos que no son los tuyos.

2.- Si la autentifica que estas realizando no es similar a la que viene por defecto en laravel no te crea las instancias de sesión que crea laravel y por lo tanto no te registra como autentificado.

En otras palabras cuando aitentificas a tu usuario debes de ejecutar

$this->guard()->user();

Lo cual crea las credenciales para la autentificacion.

3.- Si utilizas un has diferente para la encriptacion de la contraseña, te puede dar conflicto al momento de utilizar el sistema de login de laravel. Dado que nunca van a coincidir las contraseñas.